# Why dictionaries appear to be reversed?

Tags: python, dictionary

Why dictionaries in python appears reversed?

```
>>> a = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4'}
>>> a
{'four': '4', 'three': '3', 'two': '2', 'one': '1'}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does "fix" mean?  What order would you prefer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dictionaries in python (and hash tables in general) are unordered. In python you can use the `sort()` method on the keys to sort them.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries have no intrinsic order. You'll have to either roll your own ordered dict implementation, use an [ordered `list` of `tuple`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291637/why-dictionaries-appear-to-be-reversed/2291727#2291727) or use an [existing ordered](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) [`dict` implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/107747/).

Comment: @myfreeweb: there are two links, and I can access them both http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html http://code.activestate.com/recipes/107747/

Answer (score 5):

**Python3.1** has an **`OrderedDict`**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> o=OrderedDict([('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3'), ('four', '4')])
>>> o
OrderedDict([('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3'), ('four', '4')])
>>> for k,v in o.items():
...  print (k,v)
... 
one 1
two 2
three 3
four 4
```

Comment: Awesome. But I've done this without ordered dicts on Python 2.

Comment: and items in Orderedicts are ordered by when the items are added to the dictionary, not by either key or item. So if you add items out of order - and OrderedDict wont help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Now you know dicts are unordered, here is how to convert them to a list which you *can* order

```
>>> a = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4'}
>>> a
{'four': '4', 'three': '3', 'two': '2', 'one': '1'}
```

**sorted by key**

```
>>> sorted(a.items())
[('four', '4'), ('one', '1'), ('three', '3'), ('two', '2')]
```

**sorted by value**

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(a.items(),key=itemgetter(1))
[('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3'), ('four', '4')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

And what is the "standard order" you would be expecting?  It is very much application dependent.  A python dictionary doesn't guarantee key ordering anyways.

In any case, you can iterate over a dictionary keys() the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as
>   an unordered set of key: value pairs

And from the [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) (about dict.items):

> CPython implementation detail: Keys
>   and values are listed in an arbitrary
>   order which is non-random, varies
>   across Python implementations, and
>   depends on the dictionary’s history of
>   insertions and deletions.

So if you need to process the dict in a certain order, sort the keys or values, e.g.:

```
>>> sorted(a.keys())
['four', 'one', 'three', 'two']
>>> sorted(a.values())
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```